# Hyperledger Fabric : Failed fetching private data from remote peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am facing an issue with writing data to implicit `PDC(Private Data Collection)`, I have 2 peers for Org1, but when I am trying to store an asset in the implicit `PDC`, I am  getting an error. when I observed the peer logs, I see below warning in the both peer1 and peer2 of Org1

```sh
2021-02-01 11:06:13.534 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 37c404 Do not know any peer in the channel( my-channel ) that matches the policies , aborting
2021-02-01 11:06:13.534 UTC [gossip.privdata] populateFromRemotePeers -> WARN 37c405 Failed fetching private data from remote peers for dig2src:[map[{969c21e10e2651ef50b29bd69dbf65eef6488dad73d0418946a2a0c474cc0a00  _implicit_org_Org1
```

I have joined the peers to the channel and configured both the peers as anchor peers, also configured the `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP` and `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` values for both peers correctly. Can anyone Please let me know, If  I miss any other configuration ?